# Impartial Queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

I am using Python and MySQL

Let’s say I have a MySQL query:

`Select * FROM table WHERE string = ‘cla apple ss`

Note that the string is compared to ‘class’ with a word ‘apple’ interjecting it

How can I make an advanced MySQL query where rows like

`The class is big` or 
`The apple is red`

will both be returned. I have tried MATCH/AGAINST and %LIKE%, but both do not seem to have the desired effect.

I’m pretty sure there must be duplicate questions regarding this topic, but i’ve searched for a while and haven’t found a solution.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is your matching logic here?  Why should `The class is big` and `The apple is red` both be matched?

Comment: what scenarios are missed when you are using `string like '%apple% or string like '%class%'`?

Comment: I believe @UdItSolanki is correct but might be you are looking for something else. If yes, then please explain it more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
where string regexp replace('cla apple ss', ' ', '|')
```